# Call variable based on content of another variable possible in BASH?

Tags: bash

Let's say, I have 3 variables, `A=1`, `B=2`, `C=3` and finally a last variable containing the name of either of them (`VAR=A`). Is it possible to call A, B, C based on VAR's content **without** 'if's?

Like `echo "${$VAR}"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
eval echo \$$VAR
```

There is also a bash-only way of doing this, using indirect reference:

```
echo ${!VAR}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was just calling someone up until someone told me the bash-only way. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 3):

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
VAR=B
echo ${!VAR}
```

Output:

> 2

Documentation (man bash):

> [If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of  the  variable  formed
>          from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the
>          value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and  ${!name[@]}  described  below.
>          The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)